# Resources don't seem to show up in Terraform state after import

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm in the middle of importing a bunch of AWS resources into Terraform by doing the following:

- put a stub resource into a `.tf` file
- `terraform import` the resource (using the same address)
- copy the relevant config out of the output of `terraform show -no-color` into a new `.tf` file

This has worked before, but now I'm doing a bunch of security groups and it doesn't seem to be working. I'll do an import:

```
terraform import aws_security_group.rds-launch-wizard-2 sg-XXXXXXXX
```

This succeeds. I would expect `aws_security_group.rds-launch-wizard-2` to show up in the output of `terraform state list` or `terraform show`, but it doesn't. I feel like maybe I'm missing something easy? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The stub resource has to have a provider that is configured with the proper AWS region. All these security groups were in us-west-2. You need this:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "rds-launch-wizard-2" { provider = aws.us_west_2 }
```

instead of this:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "rds-launch-wizard-2" {}
```

This assumes you have a provider already configured thus:

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-west-2"
  alias   = "us_west_2"
}
```